# GLSL, способы вывода информации

Tags: glsl, стеганография

Позволяет ли GLSL каким-либо образом передать информацию из шейдера обратно в программу. Насколько мне известно, с помощью переменных с квалификатором uniform можно передать информацию в шейдер, но вернуть ее обратно не получится, так как uniform в шейдере доступны только для чтения. Так вот есть какой либо собособ вообще? Может быть доступна запись в файл или еще какой нибудь способ получить информацию из шейдера?

А задча вообще такая: [Steganography Pixel Shader](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.ru/2010/06/steganography.html).
Это пример стеганографии на шейдере, в частности алгоритм извлечения изображения, которое сокрыто в другом изображении.

В моем случае, в изображении скрывается текст, и хорошо бы после его извлечения из картинки, каким нибудь образом получить обратно в программу. Отсюда и вышеописанный мною вопрос.

Comment: Да, вам нужно [отрендерить результат в текстуру,](http://blog.angusforbes.com/openglglsl-render-to-texture/) а после этого с этой текстурой вы уже можете делать все что угодно.

Comment: Кстати, что значит этот код по ссылку на алгоритм выше:
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main(void)
{
   gl_Position = vec4(gl_Vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0 );
   texCoord = 0.5 * gl_Position.xy + vec2(0.5);     
}

не пойму зачем texCoord вычисляется таким образом? но если просто написать texCoord = gl_Position.xy, то в результате выводится шум, а не картинка.

Answer (score 2):

Да, вам нужно отрендерить результат в текстуру, а после этого с этой текстурой вы уже можете делать все что угодно

*P.S. ссылку убрал, т.к. она битая*